# For an arbitrary symmetric matrix, the relation between the number of eigenvalues and the rank of the matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For an arbitrary symmetric matrix $A\in \mathcal{S}^n$, $n$ symmetric space:

1. what is the relation between the number of eigenvalues and the rank of $A$ ?
2. If we know $rank(A) = r$, what is the spectral decomposition ?

Comment: What is $\mathcal S^n_+?$

Comment: That is usually the conventional notation for symmetric, PSD matrices.  @Omnomnomnom

Answer (score 1):

For an $n \times n$ real symmetric matrix of rank $r$, $n-r$ is the dimension of the null space, thus the multiplicity of the eigenvalue $0$.  So there are at most
$r + 1$ distinct eigenvalues.  If $1 \le r \le n-1$, then there are at least $2$ distinct eigenvalues (of which one is $0$).

Comment: Your first statement is true for any matrix @RobertIsrael.  Can you explain how your second statement "So there are at most $r+1$ distinct eigenvalues" follows from your first statement?

Comment: The sum of the multiplicities is $n$, so if $0$ has multiplicity $n-r$, the others have sum at most $r$.  Thus there are at most $r$ nonzero eigenvalues.

Comment: i see.  and the number of nonzero eigenvalues equals the number of singular values, hence my answer below.  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The number of nonzero singular values is exactly the rank of the matrix.  So to your point 2), this means there are $r$ singular values in the spectral decomposition.